# Unable to get the Get Parameters of RewriteCond in RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am unable to get the 2nd  `GET` parameters which i defined in `RewriteCound` here is the rule what i wrote:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cmtpage=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^forums/139638-ideas/suggestions/([0-9]*)((-[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*)\?cmtpage=(\d+)$ suggestion.php?id=$1&cmtpage=%1 [NC,L]
```

for example The expected Result of URL should be like this:

```
forums/139638-ideas/suggestions/2489549-ability-to-print?cmtpage=2
```

is something wrong with my regex or syntax is wrong?? where `cmtpage` is the get parameter i am unable to get

Comment: And how is the incoming URL?

Comment: @faa Here it is like that: suggestion.php?id=139638&cmtpage=2

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do, but if the query has 2 key-value pairs, the condition `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cmtpage=(\d+)$` can't have the leading `^`. It denotes it is the first pair but it is the second one.

Comment: @faa simple i am getting the first parameter from the URL its working fine i.e. id parameter but i am unable to get the 2nd parameter that is cmtpage which i am unable to get?

Comment: I think I am starting to understand. Is `The expected URL..` the incoming URL? If so, what you need is to redirect this `forums/139638-ideas/suggestions/2489549-ability-to-print?cmtpage=2` to this `suggestion.php?id=2489549&cmtpage=2` Right?

Comment: Actually its the opposite one the incoming URL is `suggestion.php?id=2489549&cmtpage=2` and i want it to be like this: `forums/139638-ideas/suggestions/2489549-ability-to-print?cmtpage=2`

Comment: Sorry if I insist in this point, but to make any rule it has to be clear. The incoming, entered URL in the browser's address bar, linked to, is `http://example.com/suggestion.php?id=2489549&cmtpage=2` and you want to map it silently to `http://example.com/forums/139638-ideas/suggestions/2489549-ability-to-print?cmtpage=2` Right? If so, where is the resource (script) for the substitution URL, it is the same incoming URL?

Comment: @faa Yes exactly this is what i want :)

Comment: Why your rule-set says the opposite, then? Sorry I can't be of any help, but it looks pretty confusing to me. Hope somebody else can help you.